# Redirecting subfolders and keeping the same /forum and url $1 after

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect 3 subfolders from

https://www.website.com/forums/forum-group/forum/directing-subfolder-information-example

to

https://www.website.com/forum/directing-subfolder-information-example <-- this is what I want

I tried

RedirectMatch 301 forums/forum-group/forum(.*) forum/$1

but it puts /forum/forum

Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be working

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^forums/forum-group/forum/(.*)$ /forum/$1
```

If you want to do it using `mod_rewrite`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^forums/forum-group/forum/(.*)$ /forum/$1 [R=301,L]
```